# Font list update

Tags: fonts

I am running `leafpad` text editor. To test various fonts, I copy a font one by one as and when required into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` directory.

Now, If I try to change the font of currently opened application, newly added font is not get reflected. I have to relaunch the application to see the newly added font.

Is there any way so that I can add font to FONTPATH and use it without closing ongoing application ?

Comment: Well, `fc-cache` should refresh your cache but I don't know if `leafpad` will re-read it. Let me know if that works and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I tried running `fc-cache -f -v` but it didn't get updated.

Comment: @terdon waiting for your answer

Comment: I don't have one. I was hoping `fc-cache` would do it.